# How to know when too much Parallel/Threads is killing performance?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, parallel-processing

I'm using several applications to process/send/retrieve data on/from the web and I'm asking if I can add more of these apps or if there are already too much apps on this server? I'm using parallel-processing for example when I need to retrieve data from several sources. Most of my classes are async (due to Mongo new queries which are async).

I'm wondering how many threads is "too much" for a CPU and is there a method to figure it out?

[image]

Here is a printscreen of my server at the moment. I can see that there are 24 logical processors, 191 processes and 3484 active threads! Could we say that this is too much ? But the CPU Utilization is only 31% ...

And for example on this server I had an app with 20 as degree of parallelism, I set it to 8 and the perfs was just the same ...

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to measure. If you add more stuff and it goes slower, you've hit a bottleneck (not necessarily CPU either).

Comment: Question: "How to know when too much Parallel/Threads is killing performance?"  Answer: When your app performance deteriorates.

Comment: Ok, testing is the key but isn't 3500 Threads for 24 Logical Processors shocking ?

Comment: 31% is "lively" but it doesn't say much if these threads are whacking Mongo.  That's throttled by your disk or network connection.  You know you have too many when adding 1 more does not drive up the number.  Start at 1.